# Issue with folder renaming in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, folder, rename

I don't have access to rename folder in this SharePoint site/library, while it appears to me I've got the 'Full Control' rights. I've sent a access request but it is sent to me.

Could you please help me to set the rights as I'm the admin of this library?

**Note**: Some contents of this site have been provided with unique permissions. (inheritage was broken)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check all the content with unique permissions - thinking about it logically, the folder which you cannot rename might have unique permissions.  So even though you have `Full Control` on the rest of the Site or Library, it is possible that the folder has unique permissions - you might only have `Read` permission.

Go to the Library Settings > Permissions > check for Unique Permissions OR check your own name and check a user's Permissions (check against your own name).

(Note: I'm using SP 2013, I've not used Online, so my answer is based on my SP 2013 knowledge, but I'd anticipate SP Online won't have fundamentally changed how Permissions work).